# Call View from separate Activity

Tags: java, android

I have 2 Activitys "MainActivity" and "MainActivity2". One Admob-Banner is shown in both Activitys at the bottom.

My Problem: I want to disable both Banners by pressing a button in my MainActivity. But as I am new to android and development in general I lack in experience. I search the internet but could not find a valid answer for my problem.

My Question: Is there a way to link both Ad-ids from separate Activitys in my method and what would be the best approach?

This is the method I call from MainActivity so far:

```
private void hide() {

    //This is the Ad from MainActivity
    final AdView adLayout = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);

    final Button disableAds = (Button) findViewById(R.id.disableAds);

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            adLayout.setEnabled(false);
            adLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            disableAds.setEnabled(false);
            disableAds.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What do you want to do actually?

Comment: I want to disable the AdView in both Activitys by only using the one method in my MainActivity

Comment: Are you calling "MainActivity2" from "MainActivity"?

Comment: I`m trying to permanently disable the adview in MainActivity2 from MainActivity. My question is if this is possible and what would be the way

Comment: My reason for this question is that if you have started "MainActivity2" from "MainActivity" then pass a boolean in intent while starting "MainActivity2" and accordingly enable/disable adview in "MainActivity2". See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do one thing when every you press the disable button save the state in Shared preferences. In Each every activity onStart() method check the state of the value. based on that value show/hide the ad-banner in your activity.

```
String MyPREFERENCES = "myPrefs" ;
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Set the Value when you click the button

```
 Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
                   editor.putString("show_ads", "no");
                   editor.commit();
```

Then onStart() method get the value of "show_ads", based on value show/hide the ADs.

```
sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
       String name=sharedpreferences.getString("show_ads", "yes");
    if(name.equals("yes")){
         adLayout.setEnabled(true);
        adLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        disableAds.setEnabled(true);
        disableAds.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      }else{
         adLayout.setEnabled(false);
        adLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        disableAds.setEnabled(false);
        disableAds.setVisibility(View.GONE);
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling "MainActivity2" from "MainActivity":

```
//Code in "MainActivity" while starting "MainActivity2":
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity2.class);
intent.putExtra("isAdDisabled", true);// pass true if ad is disabled otherwise false
startActivity(intent);

//Code in onCreate of "MainActivity2":
Intent intent = getIntent();
boolean isAdDisabled = intent.getBooleanExtra("isAdDisabled", false);

if(isAdDisabled){
    // code to hide adview
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a shared preference to store a boolean (isAdsDisabled) in your main activity when you click a button.

```
Editor editor = context.getSharedPreferences("ADS_PREF", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putBoolean(ADS_DIABLED, isAdsDisabled);
```

you can query this again when you want to show the ad in the second activity to decide whether it should be displayed or not.

you can do this by using

```
SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("ADS_PREF", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
boolean isAdsDisabled = preferences.getBoolean(ADS_DIABLED, false);
```

you can check the value of isAdsDisabled to decide it.